# What are dapps? Can torrent clients be considered as dapps?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, decentralized-applications

What are dapps? Can torrent clients be considered as dapps, since we have peer to peer data flow in torrent clients?

Answer (score 0):

Dapps are decentralized applications where the users perform functions that are necessary to operate the service. The Tor protocol is decentralized. A Tor client is a single node on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Dapps are decentralized applications. In many cases their code is written in "smart contracts", compiled, and sent to many different "nodes" on a blockchain to be served to users. The difference between normal apps and dapps is mainly that the latter is hosted in a decentralized fashion rather than from a single server/vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Decentralized applications (dApps) are digital applications or programs that exist and run on a blockchain or peer-to-peer (P2P) network of computers instead of a single computer. DApps (also called "dapps") are outside the purview and control of a single authority. DApps—which are often built on the Ethereum platform—can be developed for a variety of purposes including gaming, finance, and social media.